# Track if any error occurs while executing SQL Files on SQL Server DB using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlcmd

We are executing the sql files on SQL Server DB using Java as shown below.

```
sqlcommand = "cmd.exe /c cd  C:\\C\\Test  && ECHO Y | CALL sqlcmd -S ServerName -Usa -P Pwd -d DBName -i "+sqlFile+" -o "+sqlOutputFileName;

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sqlcommand);
int processValue = p.waitFor();
```

This will write the output to a log file.

Now we are reading this log file to check if script execution is successful without any errors. If there are any errors, we have to stop executing the next sql files. For doing this we are reading each line of Output file and checking for the below condition

```
if(line.contains("Msg") && line.contains("State")&& line.contains("Line")){
  scriptFailed = true;
  break;
}
```

Our assumption is that, whenever we get any error, the output file definetly contains the following tags like Msg, Level, State, Line etc. Sample error below

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server ServerName, Line 3
Invalid column name 'MAT_COD'.
```

Is this sufficient to check if the script execution is success or not. If there are any other conditions, please let us know.

Also, is there any setting in sqlcmd to check if the script execution is success or not.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a JDBC connection to apply your sql instead, it would throw an exception that you could catch and handle many kinds of issues and do different kinds logging.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Comment: I need to execute set of sql files which contains thousands of lines. It cannot be done by creating a JDBC connection.